# Troubleshooting span traffic shutdown interface?

Tags: linux, logs

I'm using guardium appilance, which has one of its port used to analyze span traffic.

The base os is linux. The span traffic stopped coming during some time of operations. I asked the network team, and was told that port was shut down on the guardium device end. I'm convinced that this activity has taken on switch level as it was unable to handle the traffic being passed through it.

Is there a command that i can run on the linux o/s that would tell exactly if the interface was shutdown ; if yes for what reason?

Thanks.

Comment: `dmesg` will contain information about an interface going down.

Comment: is it located in var/log? directory.

Comment: No, `dmesg` is a command that reads the kernel message buffer, `/proc/kmesg`. If you are using something like `klogd`, it may be also in /var/log.